# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ABDC.File encodeWithCoder:]:

Tags: ios, swift4.2

Hi I am trying to save the data which is in my model class using Userdefaults but It's getting crashed by giving a reason:

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[abcd.File encodeWithCoder:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2806ff2a0'"

I have given my model class and code which I have tried below. Here File is my model class which is having strings and integers. Can anyone help me to solve this, Would be great.

```
//Constants class
  static let sharedInstance = Constants()

    //to manager dev or production

    let _UserDefaults = UserDefaultsConstants()
    var file: [File] = []

    func setFile(filee:[File]) {
        file = filee
        //save to userdefaults
        self._UserDefaults.setFileData(file: filee)
    }


    func getFile() -> [File] {
        if file != file {
            return file
        }
        return self._UserDefaults.getFileData()
    }

//Userdefaults Class

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var emptyfile: [File] = []

    func save() {
        defaults.synchronize()
    }

    func setFileData(file: [File]) {
        let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: file)
        defaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "UserDefaultsResult")

    }

    func getFileData() -> [File] {
        if let myFile = defaults.value(forKey: "UserDefaultsResult") as? File {
            emptyfile = [myFile]
            return emptyfile
        }
        return emptyfile
    }
    func remove() {
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "UserDefaultsResult")
    }



//Controller class

    Constants.sharedInstance._UserDefaults.setFileData(file: [self.filee])//Crashing here
            Constants.sharedInstance._UserDefaults.save()
```

Comment: The error states that `File` must be a subclass of `NSObject` and must adopt `NSCoding`. And your code doesn't work anyway because you have to **un**archive the saved object

Comment: Here File is subclass of srKObject and I am using SharkORM here

Comment: I have no idea what `srKObject` is but obviously it does not conform to `NSCoding`.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom class 'File' should implement the endcode and decode methods.

Here is an example:

```
class Player {

var name = ""

func encodeWithCoder(encoder: NSCoder) {
    encoder.encodeObject(name)
}

func initWithCoder(decoder: NSCoder) -> Player {
    self.name = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as String
    return self
}

init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    self.name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as String
}

init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
}
}
```